# Connecting to WPA network in FreeBSD

Tags: networking, terminal, freebsd, wpa-supplicant, wpa

For whatever reason I am having a very annoying time just trying to connect to a network in FreeBSD. So the question is how would someone manually connect to a wireless WPA network in FreeBSD 11.0? Since I cannot connect to the internet to use the ports collection, no tools that are not included with the installation can be used.

Additional info:

- `ifconfig` shows wlan0 listed as well as alc0 and lo0
- NIC is an Intel AC 3160
- drivers for the NIC are already loaded in kernel
- `ifconfig wlan0 scan` shows available networks as expected.
- I think my `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` is configured correctly but is not causing wlan0 to change its ssid to the specified network

Answer (score 1):

Add an entry for this network to **/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf**. If the file does not exist, create it. Replace myssid and mypsk with your SSID and PSK

```
network={
         ssid="myssid"
         psk="mypsk"
}
```

Add entries to **/etc/rc.conf** to configure the network on startup:

```
wlans_ath0="wlan0"
ifconfig_wlan0="WPA SYNCDHCP"
```

Restart the computer, or restart the network service to connect to the network

```
service netif restart
```

Comment: That should be `wlans_iwm0="wlan0"` for the AC 3160.

Comment: I have done everything here and I am still having issues. What I am mainly looking for is the command to change the ssid and psk for the wlan0 interface. I tried viewing the ifconfig man page but it's huge.